# Setting soapui connection timeout programmatically from WsdlRequest

Tags: java, soapui, connection-timeout

I would like to know a way to set a connection timeout in Soapui java.

I am using soapui version 4.0.1.0

What i have found so far is reading timeout but what i need now is setting a connection timeout.
This question was asked before but no specific answers were given.

Here is my code so far.
It sends and retrieves requests like i want. 
But my problem is handling timeouts.
And if possible i would like to ensure if the read timeout is in milliseconds.

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    WsdlProject project = null;
    WsdlInterface[] interfacesInWSDL = null;
    try {
        SoapUI.setSoapUICore(new StandaloneSoapUICore(true));
        project = new WsdlProject();
        interfacesInWSDL = WsdlInterfaceFactory.importWsdl(project, "wsdlPath.wsdl", true);
        for (int i = 0; i < interfacesInWSDL.length; i++) {
            for (Operation op : interfacesInWSDL[i].getOperationList()) {
                WsdlOperation operation = (WsdlOperation) op;
                WsdlRequest request = operation.addNewRequest("WSDLRequest");
                request.setTimeout("10000");//Read timeout
                request.setEndpoint("URL");
                request.setRequestContent(operation.createRequest(true));

                System.out.println(request.getRequestContent());

                WsdlSubmitContext submitContext = new WsdlSubmitContext(request);
                WsdlSubmit submit = (WsdlSubmit) request.submit(submitContext, false);
                Response response = submit.getResponse();

                System.out.println(response.getContentAsString());

            }
        }
    } catch (Exception ex) {
        //Exception Logger
    }
}
```

Thank you in advance.

Comment: What is happening in the statement `request.setTimeout("10000");`?

Comment: What i know is that it sets the timeout for waiting for a response from the endpoint in milliseconds.. What i would like o know is how to set the timeout for waiting for a connection between me and the endpoint given